# reading a file on any device

Tags: c#, file, console-application, streamreader

The map for the RPG I'm making is stored in a .txt file (it's all ascii). The way I show the game where my map is located now is this:

```
map = @"D:\personal\tests\Tests\ascii map tools\map1.txt";
        DrawMap(map); //this is my map drawing subroutine
        //It reads the file character by character and prints it in the console.

        //It uses the following command to find my map:
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(map);
```

The issue with this way is that if I want to play the game on another device (only windows pc's), it has to have the exact same path to the file I need to read. Is there a way for the game to automatically find the file, wherever it is? If so, how would I put that in my code?

Comment: What devices are we talking about, Mobile devices, or just other computers

Comment: @TheGeneral only windows computers, I don't want to overcomplicate things yet, because i'm just beginning with programming. I've immediately edited my post to make it clear to other people as well.

Comment: Normally you would just resolve the file relative to either the exe location, or some configured/setting location (perhaps defaulting to a subfolder of the user-profile); are none of these options?

Comment: how about installing dropbox or similar and getting it there

Comment: @kenny you'd still have to find the dropbox folder which isn't necessarily the same on all machines, also if he wants to share the application he'd need to share the dropbox folder with all his users who'd have to use dropbox too, that doesn't sound like a step in the right direction at all

Comment: You need to develop the application and the installers (or other deployment mechanisms) together. User unzipping into a single user folder could be a workable plan. But, under Windows, applications and data are usually separate and applications are either for all users or an individual user. See [Environment.SpecialFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=netframework-4.7.2). Also, applications can implement a "first run" experience that could initialize user data. So, please [edit] you question with the approach you want to take.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply bring the file along with the exe (in visual studio right click the file => properties => copy always or copy if newer depending on what you want). This means the file will get copied to the same folder as the executable.

Then you only have to replace

```
map = @"D:\personal\tests\Tests\ascii map tools\map1.txt";
```

with

```
map = @"map1.txt";
```

Comment: This would read from the working directory at the time the file is opened. Many launch mechanisms (such as double-clicking in File Explorer) do initialize the working directory to the .exe folder so it would work (except when it doesn't).